# Why intelliJ doesn't show maven dependency as External dependencies and also shows red symbols even though the dependencies are downloaded

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm cloning my maven project from GIT and then doing mvn clean install. My dependencies are downloaded successfully, but I'm not able to see it in External Libraries. Also my code shows red colored as if dependencies are not available. I did Invalidate cache/restart, did re-cloning, removed .idea folder, but no luck.

Any solution to this?

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have opened the Project as Maven project and that it has been imported successfully from Maven pom.xml build file. In an existing project you can import Maven from Maven tool window. See [Link a Maven project﻿](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#link_maven_project)
 steps:

1. Open the Maven tool window.
2. In the Maven tool window, click the `+` icon to attach a Maven project.
3. In the dialog that opens, select the desired `pom.xml` file, and click OK.